# Recursive function that has an array of integers and it's size as parameters that will return true if the sum of the array elements is even?

Tags: java, recursion, boolean

How do I create a function that has an array of integers and the array's length as parameters that will return true if the sum of the array elements is even and false otherwise?

How would I do this without using any static variables?

I've tried making a code that will check if,
current is odd and previous is even will return false recursively, else will return true recursively, this idea is based on the mathematical axiom that only even plus odd is equal to odd, every other combination is even.

```
public static boolean q3(int[] arr, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return arr[index] % 2 == 0;
    }
    if (arr[index] % 2 == 0) {//if current is even 
        if (!q3(arr, index - 1)) {//even plus odd = odd
            return false;
        } else
            return true;  //every other combo equal true 
    } else if (q3(arr, index - 1)) {//if current is odd 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: With recursion, you need to identify the base case.  In this case, if the array is empty, the sum is zero which is even so return true.  Then you identify the case when the array has N elements.  Look at the last element and note if it is even or odd, and then recursively call the function with the same array passing N-1 as the length and get back the value it returns.  If both first element and remaining sum are the same (both odd or both even), then the sum is even, otherwise it is odd.  Return true or false accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 versions, one with recursion, other with no recursion

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      int[] arr={5, 3, 1};
      System.out.println("sum of "+Arrays.toString(arr)+" is " + size_ispair_rec(arr, arr.length));
      
    }
    
    public static boolean size_ispair_rec(int[] arr, int size){

        if(size-1 == 0){
            return arr[size]%2==0;
        }
        
        return !((arr[size-1]%2 == 0) ^ size_ispair_rec(arr, size-1));

    }
    
    public static boolean size_ispair(int[] arr, int size){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        return sum%2 == 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks, also I wasn't aware that java had a xor operator(^), so thanks for that

Comment: NP, I searched for it too when figuring out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive method that does the job. I've tried to keep the code readable.

The idea is that the only time you get an even number by addition is when

1. Both the numbers are even
2. Both the numbers are odd

At every recursive call, we check if adding the number to the previous calculated value makes it even or odd.

```
public static boolean isSumEven(int arr[], int length){
        if(length == 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            boolean sumPreviousElemsEven = isSumEven(arr, length - 1);
            boolean currentElemEven = arr[length-1]%2 == 0 ? true : false;
            if(sumPreviousElemsEven && currentElemEven || !sumPreviousElemsEven && !currentElemEven){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you did always comes back true.

Comment: @David How are you testing the code?

Here is an example:
`public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
       int arr2[] = {3,1,1};
       int arr3[] = {};
       System.out.println(isSumEven(arr, arr.length));//true
       System.out.println(isSumEven(arr2, arr2.length));//false
       System.out.println(isSumEven(arr3, arr3.length));//true
    }
    
    ... 
}`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, in my main I was sending the length of the array minus one, you did it differently. I fixed the problem and it now works fine. thanks!

Comment: You had mentioned **create a function that has an array of integers and the array's length as parameters**, hence the same on the method. Glad it worked for you.